# First-most application icon on dash hidden until GNOME shell restarts

Tags: icons, gnome-shell

(using Ubuntu 19.04, GNOME 3.32)

Upon upgrading from 18.04, and then from 18.10, I had noticed that the first icon on my dash (Firefox in my case) shrinks to a tiny, barely noticeable square (shown below) until the GNOME shell is either restarted or the Firefox icon is removed and then added back to the dash. This behaviour seems to persist even with other icons, as I had once temporarily removed the Firefox icon and restarted my computer, only to see that the new first icon (what was after Firefox, the terminal in this case) became shrunken and hidden, too.

[image]

Again, this resolves itself upon restarting the shell (e.g. via Alternate + F2, and then issuing the `r` command), but this bug appears upon each startup.

Comment: You probably have a GNOME extension problem. Dash to Dock installed? That may be your problem. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.